# What is the best way to write different css or scss for the same component?

Tags: javascript, css, design-patterns, sass

Imagine that I have a complex component like a dropdown menu and I want it to have some custom styles when I use it in different places. Not only colors, but spacing and icons too.

If I'm using something like react, or vue, I could pass parameters to the props.

We can also use only scss, and there are a lot of ways of overwriting the styles:

```
.dropdown{
 width: 100px
}

//overwrite for my custom menu
.my-custom-menu{
 .dropdown{
   width: 120px;
  }
}
```

Or if using something like BEM, I could even make the main class name a variable and change it:

```
.dropdown{
  &__container{
    width: 100px;
  }
}

//custom
.other-dropdown{
 &__container{
   width: 120px;
  }
}
```

What is the best way? Are there other ways of doing this?

Comment: There's not really a "best". I can think of a few more, [SMACSS](http://smacss.com/), [OOCSS](https://www.slideshare.net/stubbornella/object-oriented-css), [ACSS](https://acss.io/), [Bulma](https://bulma.io/), and [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/) to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

Make your component re-usable. You just add style for modifed states or context like dark, light big, small** etc.

```
.dropdown{
  &__container{
    width: 100px;
  }
}

//custom

.dropdown{
 
 &.dark {
  color: dark;
 }
 
 
 &.light {
  color: white;
 }
  
}
```

And this is work for all components so far.

you had:

```
--dropdown
--dropdown__container
--container-small
--container-big
```